# Drawing shapes and saving file into text, encoding and decoding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need assistance with saving drawn shapes on a winform using graphics from a list I created that store the shape type and the information for the shape the user draws, into a text file that encodes it into UTF8 (or to their choosing).

My problem is after saving the "drawing", which has shape type lines, rectangle, etc. as a text file. How do I open it in the winform application and parse the numbers and re-create the shape on the winform using graphics and paint event?

What I currently have in code, is the user draws shapes onto a graphic handled by mouse events, and then it goes into a list. The user also selects the encoding type for the text file (like Encoding.ASCII, etc.) Then I have a save menu where the user saves the file into a location. There is also a clear button to clear the drawings and such. Then I can't figure out how to open the text file to re-create that saved drawing that was cleared.

I looked at the msdn API about creating my own format for the encoding, but I'm confused on how to do it.

What I thought about doing was checking what encoding the user saved it, and then choosing the appropriate custom format to re-create the shape on the winform graphic.

Any ideas? Thank you.

EDIT:
The code I'm using for saving the text file:

```
                using (BinaryWriter save_bin = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(save_fd.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    foreach (Shape a in shapeList)
                    {
                        save_bin.Write(a.ToString());
                    }
                    save_bin.Close();
                }
```

I think I should not use ToString(), but something else to write.

Comment: Encoding could be done with xml, easy to store all the properties contained within the shape.

Comment: I open the text file in notepad and see the properties. When I open it using FileOpenDialog in the winform app, how can I know what property is what so I can use the createshape method? I added more to my post, in case I'm doing the encoding thing wrong.

Comment: that's up to you, who creates the encoding. You can also create a class for each shape with all of the attributes, and then serialize them into xml or even binary

Comment: @AnthonyDekimpe Thanks for the tip, do you have a reference I can look at for turning it into binary?

Comment: Question feel too broad for me... Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614318/whats-the-difference-between-a-streamwriter-and-a-binarywriter. Consider using JSON if you need to serialize your data as instead of inventing your own format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More info on serialization:

Firstly, your classes should contain the [Serializable] attribute

```
[Serializable]
public class Example()
{

}
```

Then you have the ability to save it like this:

```
Example obj = new Example();

// Set properties of the 'Example' object

IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); // Save the file
Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
stream.Close();
```

Restoring the file back to your class can be done like this:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
MyObject obj = (MyObject) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do this, from NuGet, download `JSON.Net`

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Next, copy this code

```
string jsonStateOfShape = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shapeList);
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("shapes.json", FileMode.Create))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(jsonStateOfShape);
}


// To re open
string reopenedState = string.Empty;
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("shapes.json", FileMode.Open))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    reopenedState = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
var shapes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shape>>(reopenedState);

shapes.ForEach(shapeList.Add);

// dont try to replace shapeList directly, referencing issues...
```

Comment: For the re open, I get an error at the line with, var shapes = , in // re open.





Error:
Additional information: Could not create an instance of type Draw.Shape. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].PenColor', line 1, position 13.

Comment: you know your shapeList variable, what type is it

Comment: FYI, Anthonys solution is better suited to your application ;) Just the way desktop apps do things by convention...