# Are StreamWriter and BinaryWriter interchangeable when it comes to write strings

Tags: c#, .net

From the MSDN pages for [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) and [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) you can clearly see the differences:

> StreamWriter:
>
> Implements a TextWriter for writing
> characters to a stream in a particular
> encoding.

And:

> BinaryWriter:
>
> Writes primitive types in binary to a
> stream and supports writing strings in
> a specific encoding.

I know that the most important feature of BinaryWriter is that it can wirte primitive types in binary, which can be more compact and efficient (consider writing the integer 23861398 - the binary writer would require 4 bytes, but the stream writer would require 8, 16, or even 32 depending on the encoding).

But when it comes to write strings, can we say StreamWriter and BinaryWriter are interchangeable?

Comment: They are not. Look at the output: they will write very different things when told to write a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the difference between a streamwriter and a binarywriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614318/whats-the-difference-between-a-streamwriter-and-a-binarywriter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the `BinaryWriter` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter.write?view=net-5.0#System_IO_BinaryWriter_Write_System_String_):

> Writes a length-prefixed string to this stream in the current encoding of the BinaryWriter, and advances the current position of the stream in accordance with the encoding used and the specific characters being written to the stream.

and:

> Length-prefixed means that this method first writes the length of the string, in bytes, when encoded with the BinaryWriter instance's current encoding to the stream. This value is written as an unsigned integer. This method then writes that many bytes to the stream.
>
> For example, the string "A" has a length of 1, but when encoded with UTF-16; the length is 2 bytes, so the value written in the prefix is 2, and 3 bytes are written to the stream, including the prefix.

The `StreamWriter` class does not write any string-lengths to the output. It just writes the text itself

Both do respect the encoding you have specified when you create the object. The actual text being written uses that encoding.

So depending on what you mean by *"interchangeable"*, they either are, or they are not. **I would say they are not**, but if all you are looking at is the sequence of bytes that represents the text written itself, one might consider them to be.

To address your comment:

> I'm new to BinaryWriter, so why it need to write length to the stream first? why not just write "real data" directly?

Unlike `StreamWriter`, which only writes one kinds of data, `BinaryWriter` can write all sorts of data, include raw bytes and various primitive types, to a single `Stream`. When writing each of these, it needs a way of indicating where that particular section of data ends. That's so that `BinaryWriter`'s reading counterpart, `BinaryReader`, has a way of knowing where each section of data ends.

For some things, it's simple, because the data item itself is fixed size. A `System.Int32` is 4 bytes, a `System.Int64` is 8, and so on. They're fixed-length, so when reading you just read the expected number of bytes.

But `string` objects are variable length. There are two common approaches to handling this: prefixing the string with a count, or terminating the string with a null character (`'\0'`). In-memory .NET strings are counted, not null-terminated, and so string objects can actually *contain* a null character, and so null-terminating the string doesn't work for storing a string in a file.

So the prefix with the count of bytes is used instead.

Comment: Thanks again. So you mean I can use BinaryWriter to write a bit, and then write string to the same stream? If that's OK, then when you use BinaryReader to read, yes you do have the size for the first section of data, but you don't track the data type, so how do you know it is an int, rather than a two characters string?

Comment: _"but you don't track the data type"_ -- therein lies the rub. To use `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` successfully, you must already know the exact order of data types. You don't need to know, e.g. the length of your strings in advance, because of the lengths being included in the written data. But you still do need to know _something_ about the data. What good would it do you otherwise? And more, you need to know not just what the data is, but what it means. Using `BinaryWriter` doesn't make those requirements magically disappear. It just provides a mechanism for formatting specific data.

Answer (score 3):

No, they're absolutely not interchangeable. `BinaryWriter` is an opinionated basic IO tool for writing to binary outputs; `StreamWriter` is for writing text outputs. Any times that the output looks similar is purely incidental - they should *absolutely not* be used interchageably.

For strings, they will *look* similar, but that's simply because both are ultimately just using a text-encoding. The boilerplate *around* them is very different though (with the `BinaryWriter` using length-prefix, etc).

If you're looking to use one as though it were the other: you're probably doing something very wrong. If you clarify what you're *trying* to do, we can probably offer guidance.